# Люди помогите найти ошибку

Tags: python

```
import random
import math
t=1
p=random.randint(-t,t)
s=p
n=int(input())
i=1
l=1
ro=1
z=n
b=1
em=4.8
ee=-1.6
e=0
v=p
pi=3,14
if n>1:
    while n!=0:
        n=n-1
        b= math.inf ** b
    n=z
else:
    n=z
while i!=0:
    if l!=e:
        if n>1:
            while n!=0:
                h=random.randint(-t,t)
                p=p+h
                v=v*h
                n=n-1
            n=z
        else:
            n=z
        s=str(s)
        x=int(s[0])
        s=int(s)
        e=((v**n)*ro)*((s//(x*x)**x)-(x*x)**x)**2
        f=(math.pi**b)/(em*ee)
        l=((f)**n)*p
        print(e,l,f,t,z,b,)
        p=0
        v=1
        t=t+1
        z=z+1
    else:
        i=0
print(l,e,p,n,s)
```

этот код должен вторым пунктом возвращать только положительную бесконечность но он возвращает периодически обычную и отрицательную

помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Я, конечно, не кандидат математических наук и не гуру питона, но мне кажется, что "обычная" бесконечность - это и есть "положительная" бесконечность

Comment: `pi=3,14` - это просто сказка.

Comment: Что вы хотите сосчитать?

Comment: Это сложно объяснить это просто была задачка размять мозги но потом я решил перевести её в код и тут пошло поехало

Answer (score 0):

если проблема только в знаках бесконечности, почему бы в модуль ответ не обернуть `abc()`

Comment: Не пойдёт так как сама программа должна выдавать ответ без модуля в само уровнение не вложен модуль

Comment: Так вы же пишете, что программа должна возвращать только положительную бесконечность и только?

Comment: ну так я писал программу по уровнению а в уровнении модуль отсутствует